# Negative Binomial Regression Assumption Testing

Tags: math, statistics, regression, poisson

First post!

I'm a biologist with limited background in applied statistics and R. Basically know enough to be dangerous, so I'd appreciate it someone could confirm/deny that I'm on the right path.

My datasets consists of count data (wildlife visits to water wells) as a response variable and multiple continuous predictor variables (environmental measurements).

First, I eliminated multicolinearity by dropping a few predictor variables. Second, I investigated the distribution of the response variable. Initially, it looked Poisson. However, a Poisson exact test came back as significant, and the variance of the response variable was around 200 with a mean around 9, i.e. overdispersed. Due to this, I decided to move forward with Negative Binomial and Quasipoisson regressions. Both selected the same model, the residuals of which are in a normal distribution. Further, a plot of residuals over predicted values is unbiased and homoscedastic.

Questions:
1. Have I selected the correct regressions to model this data?
2. Are there additional assumptions of the NBR and QpR that I need to test? How should I/Where can I learn about how to do these?
3. Did I check for overdispersion correctly? Is there a difference in comparing the mean and variance vs comparing the conditional mean and variance of the response variable?
4. While the NBR and QpR called the same model, is there a way to select which is the "better" approach?
5. I would like to eventually publish. Are there more analyses I should perform on my selected model?

Comment: Great question, Patrick, but I fear it does not belong on SO.  I think you'll have better luck on the Statistics SE site.

Comment: Cross Validated is the site you want: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks! I'll move it over there.